# Setting up ServiceControllerServiceProvider in Silex with YAML

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, silex

Reading ServiceControllerServiceProvider http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html

I wish to DI over Service Location so that my Controllers can inject Dependencies inside the constructor instead of the function.

However my Application uses YAML for routing and not PHP like the example.

This is my routing:

```
protected function registerRouteService()
{
    $app = $this;
    $this['routes'] = $this->extend(
        'routes',
        function (RouteCollection $routes) use ($app) {
            $loader = new YamlRouting(new FileLocator($app::$rootPath . $app::DEFAULT_ROUTES_PATH));
            $collection = $loader->load($app::DEFAULT_ROUTES_FILE);
            $routes->addCollection($collection);

            return $routes;
        }
    );
}
```

This function is protected because I am extending the Silex\Application in order to bootstrap up everything.

As per the document I have invoked the serviceprovider:

`$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());`

My issue is that because I use YAML the following section of the document - I don't know how to apply it in general since

```
$app['posts.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new PostController($app['posts.repository']);
});

$app->get('/posts.json', "posts.controller:indexJsonAction");
```

Comment: How can you add a parameter to:

$app->get('/posts.json', "posts.controller:indexJsonAction");

in order to be processed in indexJsonAction function?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to work just as it would with routes declared in php, the service provider doesn't really have any impact until the controller is resolved from the router, so you should be fine with

```
# $app::$rootPath . $app::DEFAULT_ROUTES_PATH
posts_json:
    path:      /posts.json
    defaults:  { _controller: posts.controller:indexJsonAction }
```

Comment: Question: must I define each $app['posts.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new PostController($app['posts.repository']);
});

for each Controller class I have in order for it to resolve?

Comment: Yes you do really. You could look at doing it with a loop and auto resolving deps etc, but that's probably more trouble than it is worth.